# Trigger plugin button using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, toolbar, pyqt4

I wrote a project macro which, when loaded, hides **all toolbars** except for one which contains a couple of my plugin buttons. I know it's possible to trigger core buttons like the following example:

```
self.iface.actionPanToSelected().trigger()
```

But is it possible to do this for a custom-made plugin?

---

I noticed I could identify the objects of the toolbar using:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QToolBar
for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolBar): 
    # x.objectName() returns the names of the toolbars
    if x.objectName() == 'Example':
        print x.children()

[<PyQt4.QtGui.QLayout object at 0x0000000023589840>, <PyQt4.QtGui.QToolButton object at 0x0000000024DCE488>, <PyQt4.QtGui.QAction object at 0x0000000024DCE510>, 
<PyQt4.QtGui.QToolButton object at 0x0000000024DCE598>, <PyQt4.QtGui.QToolButton object at 0x0000000024DCE620>]
```

But unsure how to trigger the buttons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is more a PyQt4 question.

I guess the best way of doing it is to give your actions an `objectName`, so that you can access them directly instead of looping through toolbars and their children.

For instance, I can give the custom name `mActionCopyLayersToClipboard` to one of my plugin buttons:

```
self.actionCopy = QAction( icon, u"Copy selected layers and groups to  clipboard (Ctrl+Ins)", self.iface.mainWindow() )
self.actionCopy.setObjectName('mActionCopyLayersToClipboard')
```

And then I can trigger it in this way:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction
iface.mainWindow().findChild( QAction, 'mActionCopyLayersToClipboard' ).trigger()
```