# Calling One Plugin from another Plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am working on various plugins in QGIS which I have made, so I was wondering if it is possible to make one plugin which would call these plugins in a predetermined order, so that I would not have to call them individually.

Comment: Which plugins are you interested in? I don't think all plugins are easily callable.

Comment: Well, most of the plugins are made by me to perform certain tasks, like making a file or modifying it. After that I use point sampling tool to get certain information from a layer, and then I have to again run another script to save the information in a different file.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to trigger plugin button using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228362/how-to-trigger-plugin-button-using-pyqgis) where you can set the `objectName` for icons for your other plugins. Then call these from your main plugin.