# How can I access a specific button in a toolbar using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to "click" a button in the "Raster Toolbar" in QGIS 2.14 via PyQGIS, but don't know how to do this correctly. I can access the toolbar itself with

```
rtools = qgis.utils.iface.rasterToolBar()
```

But after that, I have no clue how to get the correct button. I think I can aceess the single buttons like this:

```
buttons = [c for c in rtools.children() if type(c) is QToolButton]
```

but I only know the hover text (e.g. "Local Histogram Stretch") and not the name or ID or whatever can be used here as an identifier. All fields which I thougt might contain something useful have been empty strings.

Does anyone know the proper way of "clicking" a button via code?

---

Just found the actual action I was searching, so I could use [Trigger plugin button using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228362) to get that specific button to be "clicked", but what if I don't know the QAction?

There must be a way of identifying the button through one of its properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the actions for a toolbutton tb using:

```
actions = tb.actions()
```

This returns a list. You can then examine the text associated with each:

```
for action in actions:
    print action.text()
```